Read Xml nodes using XmlDocument without namespace
I need to parse and read an xml using vb.net 4.0 XmlDocument, the problem is that xml does not have namespace, I have a working code which uses XElement, but need to use XmlDocument and can't import Xml.Linq so XElement is not an option for me:
Dim MyXML As XElement = XElement.Load(MemoryStream)
Dim count As Integer = Integer.Parse(MyXML.@elementCount)
For Each MyXElement As XElement In MyXML.Elements
    Dim Components As String() = MyXElement.@OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor.Split()
    R = Single.Parse(Components(0).Substring(2))
    G = Single.Parse(Components(1).Substring(2))
    B = Single.Parse(Components(2).Substring(2))
    EName = MyXElement.@OPFCategoryCopyName
Next

And here's my Xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories elementCount="18">
  <category xml:space="preserve" OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor="r:0.57 g:0.48 b:0.82" OPFCategoryCopyName="Birthday"></category>
  <category xml:space="preserve" OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor="r:0.45 g:0.60 b:0.88" OPFCategoryCopyName="Blue category"></category>
  <category xml:space="preserve" OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor="r:0.92 g:0.79 b:0.40" OPFCategoryCopyName="Brown Category"></category>
  <category xml:space="preserve" OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor="r:0.63 g:0.26 b:0.80" OPFCategoryCopyName="Family"></category>
</categories>

Now, if I use XmlDocument Load/LoadXml how can I obtain elementCount number and OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor/OPFCategoryCopyName?
Any tip or help is greatelt appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

This worked for me:
Using ms as MemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><categories " ...))
    Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument
    doc.Load(ms)
    
    Console.WriteLine("elementCount: " & doc.SelectSingleNode("/categories/@elementCount").Value)
    
    For Each el As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/categories/category")
        Console.WriteLine("OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor: " & el.Attributes.GetNamedItem("OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor").Value)
    Next
End Using

with the output:
elementCount: 18
OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor: r:0.57 g:0.48 b:0.82
OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor: r:0.45 g:0.60 b:0.88
OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor: r:0.92 g:0.79 b:0.40
...

If there were namespaces in the XML, then this question could be used.

oh thanks, excellent, just one thing, both will work:
el.Attributes.GetNamedItem("OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor").Value
vs
el.Attributes("OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor").Value
so which one is safer or recommended to use?

Well, second one is shorter, so it'd be probably preferable

If you can use System.Xml.Serialization, this is a good option.
Create a model for your file
<XmlRoot("categories")> Public Class Categories
    <XmlAttribute("elementCount")> Public Property ElementCount As Integer
    <XmlElement("category")> Public Property Categories As List(Of Category)
End Class
Public Class Category
    <XmlIgnore> Public Property R As Double
    <XmlIgnore> Public Property G As Double
    <XmlIgnore> Public Property B As Double
    <XmlAttribute("xml:space")> Public Property Space As String
    <XmlAttribute> Public Property OPFCategoryCopyName As String
    <XmlAttribute> Public Property OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor As String
        Get
            Return $"r:{R:0.00} g:{G:0.00} b:{B:0.00}"
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Dim s = value.Split(" "c)
            R = Double.Parse(s(0).Split(":"c)(1))
            G = Double.Parse(s(1).Split(":"c)(1))
            B = Double.Parse(s(2).Split(":"c)(1))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Parse the file into the classes
Dim se As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Categories))
Dim cs = DirectCast(se.Deserialize(MemoryStream), Categories)
Dim count = cs.ElementCount
For Each c In cs.Categories
    Dim r = c.R
    Dim g = c.G
    Dim b = c.B
    Dim space = c.Space
    Dim name = c.OPFCategoryCopyName
Next

The interpretation of the colors is done in the model, further simplifying the end-user's job.
If you are modifying the file and writing the changes, the OPFCategoryCopyBackgroundColor.Get handles the formatting.
se.Serialize(*stream*, cs)

